# How to choose between BasicMed an a Class III Medical?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical, basicmed

I'm due for a medical this year, and my last one was before the BasicMed program existed.

I'm a VFR PPL, flying small planes with 6 people or less.

Is there a clear reason to use Basic Med or Class III Medical?

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/42908/62)

Comment: How long ago? Your most recent medical certificate must have expired after July 15, 2006, to be eligible for BasicMed. (10 years before the law was passed, not 10 years before the current date as many believe.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on whether you intend to fly a larger aircraft at higher altitudes at faster speeds or one with a limited number of passengers at lower altitiudes and airspeeds.  If the latter is going to be the only flying you do, then a basic medical will be a good choice.  If you intende to undergo additional training and obtain additional certificates, ratings, or type ratings, I believe you will be required to hold at least a third class medical to do so.

Comment: FWIW, you can take a checkride with BasicMed; see the updated wording in 61.23. That might or might not be important, as you said.

Comment: I don’t know that for sure.  It may well be that the FARs have recently been updated to include this. But the current 2018 FAR states that you need at least a third class Medical to apply for a certificate or a rating.  I talked with the medical certification division in OKC and they thought one could apply for a certificate with a basic med but wasn’t totally sure.  I’ll have to ask a DPE in the field to see if they’re cleared by OKC to accept a basic med from an applicant for a checkride.

Comment: I'm not sure what source you mean by "the current 2018 FAR" but if you look at 61.23 on ecfr.gov the text in 61.23(a)(3) allows using BasicMed as an exception to a third-class medical for a checkride. I've answered your other question anyway, hopefully it's helpful.